# Regex to get the word after specific match words

Tags: regex

I am trying to pull the dollar amount from some invoices. I need the match to be on the word *directly after* the word "TOTAL". Also, the word total may sometimes appear with a colon after it (ie `Total:`). An example text sample is shown below:

> 4 Discover Credit Purchase - c REF#: 02353R TOTAL: **40.00** AID: 1523Q1Q TC: mzQm 40.00 CHANGE 0.00 TOTAL NUMBER OF ITEMS SOLD = 0 12/23/17 Ql:38piii 414 9 76 1G6 THANK YOU FOR SHOPPING KR08ER Now Hiring - Apply Today!

In the case of the sample above, the match should be `"40.00"`.

The Regex statement that I wrote:

```
(?<=total)([^\n\r]*)
```

pulls EVERYTHING after the word "total". I only want the very next word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This (unlike other answers so far) matches *only* the total amount (ie without needing to examine groups):

```
((?<=\bTOTAL\b )|(?<=\bTOTAL\b: ))[\d.]+
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/aM1PAlTGGh) matching when input has, and doesn’t have, the colon after `TOTAL`.

The reason 2 look behinds (which don’t capture input) are needed is they can’t have variable length. The optional colon is handled by using an alternation (a regex OR via `...|...`) of 2 look behinds, one with and one without the colon.

If `TOTAL` can be in any case, add `(?i)` (the *ignore case* flag) to the start of the regex.

Comment: This seems to be doing the trick! It matches ONLY the total amount which is what I needed.

Comment: This is neat, +1. However would it not be better to have `(?:(?<=\bTOTAL\b )|(?<=\bTOTAL\b: ))[\d.]+` instead of `((?<=\bTOTAL\b )|(?<=\bTOTAL\b: ))[\d.]+`  to avoid the capturing ?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness regex is practically a write-only language, so I rank readability over (minuscule) performance. In this case, captured groups are irrelevant because the *whole* match is the target, so I can omit the `?:` noise without loss of effectiveness yet gaining (albeit slight) readability. As for “performance” reasons, you would have great difficulty detecting a measurable difference.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is match total followed by an optional colon `:?` and zero or more times a whitespace character `\s*` and capture in a group one or more digits followed by an optional part that matches a dot and one or more digits.

To match an upper or lowercase variant of total you could make the match case insensitive by for example by adding a [modifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) `(?i)` or use a case insensitive flag.

[`\btotal:?\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`](https://regex101.com/r/w9ufj5/2)

The value `40.00` will be in group 1.

Comment: Will it match "TOTAL"?

Comment: You have to use case insensitive.

Comment: It will either match "total" or "total:" but it should NOT be case sensitive. However, the query you provided includes the word total. I only want the word AFTER the word total.

Comment: +1, however according to the regex flavor it would also be possible to use the reset operator as `\btotal:?\s*\K\d+(?:\.\d+)?` to prevent capturing.

Answer (score 1):

Explanations are in the regex pattern.

```
string str = "4 Discover Credit Purchase - c REF#: 02353R TOTAL: 40.00 AID: 1523Q1Q";
string pattern = @"(?ix)       # 'i' means case-insensitive search
                    \b         # Word boundary
                    total      # 'TOTAL' or 'total' or any other combination of cases
                    :?         # Matches colon if it exists
                    \s+        # One or more spaces
                    (\d+\.\d+) # Sought number saved into group
                    \s         # One space";
// The number is in the first group: Groups[1]
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(str, pattern).Groups[1].Value);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below regex to get amount after TOTAL:

```
\bTOTAL\b:?\s*([\d.]+)
```

It will capture the amount in first group.

Link : https://regex101.com/r/tzze8J/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern: `TOTAL:? ?(\d+.\d+)[^\d]?`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qMEtAf/1)